# Which plugin is required to enable "Execute windows batch command" in action step of Flexible publish in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using **Jenkins 1.609**. 
I have a job in which in the post-build step, i have added flexible publish step. I have installed **Flexible publish plugin** for this.

Now, I have the requirement where in i need to execute windows batch command in action step of Flexible publish. By default, "Execute windows batch command" step is not available in the drop-down list for adding action. I need to know which additional plugin i will have to install so that this option will also get available in the drop-down list.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Is this the plugin you are looking for - [Xshell plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/XShell+Plugin)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, this plugin seems to be of no help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in Any build-step plugin.

Comment: How to use it? There is no doc on plug-in page.

Comment: The answer is not clear, please give more info on how to use it.